# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_length' django charfield

Tags: python, django

I have a custom charfield and the **init** function tells me max_length is unexpected

```
class field(CharField):

    description = _("CharField")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 10
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'form_class': fields.field}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super().formfield(**defaults)
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 614, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 233, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1653, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1534, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1567, in _changeform_view
    fieldsets = self.get_fieldsets(request, obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 335, in get_fieldsets
    return [(None, {'fields': self.get_fields(request, obj)})]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 326, in get_fields
    form = self._get_form_for_get_fields(request, obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 666, in _get_form_for_get_fields
    return self.get_form(request, obj, fields=None)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 709, in get_form
    return modelform_factory(self.model, **defaults)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 555, in modelform_factory
    return type(form)(class_name, (form,), form_class_attrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 253, in __new__
    fields = fields_for_model(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 179, in fields_for_model
    formfield = formfield_callback(f, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 182, in formfield_for_dbfield
    return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/computer/Desktop/hanohov/main/models.py", line 57, in formfield
    return super().formfield(**defaults)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1042, in formfield
    return super().formfield(**defaults)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 929, in formfield
    return form_class(**defaults)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/main/account/add/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_length'
```

I don't understand, django says charfield must have max_length.

```
class field(Field):
    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid': _('Enter a valid ID number.'),
    }

    def clean(self, value):
        value = super().clean(value)
        id_number_re = re.compile(r'^(?P<number>\d{1,8})-?(?P<check>\d)$')
        if value in EMPTY_VALUES:
            return ''

        match = id_number_re.match(value)
        if not match:
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid'], code='invalid')

        value = match.group('number') + match.group('check')
        if not luhn.is_valid(value):
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid'], code='invalid')
        return value
```

Comment: Can you please add the import statements? and the *full* traceback?

Comment: What exactly is `fields.field`? Whatever *that* is doesn't accept a `max_length` argument.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I added it.

Comment: @deceze it doesn't matter because we are converting it to charfield.

Comment: No, it *does* matter, because that's what's complaining about the unexpected argument! `form_class(**defaults)` is raising the error, and `form_class` at that point is `fields.field`.

Comment: @deceze It's added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom form widget `fields.field` class doesn't accept a `max_length` argument, which `models.CharField.formfield` adds by default (when you call `super().formfield(**defaults)`).

Either you add an `__init__` to your `field` class which accepts (and perhaps simply discards) the `max_length` argument. Or have your `field` class inherit from `forms.fields.CharField` instead of `forms.fields.Field`.

Alternatively you completely override the `formfield` method to not add that argument. Which means you basically need to bypass the `models.CharField.formfield` implementation and call `models.Field.formfield` directly:

```
def formfield(self, **kwargs):
    defaults = {'form_class': fields.field}
    defaults.update(kwargs)
    return super(CharField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

Not necessarily the most elegant solution, as it relies on a lot of internal implementation details like the specific inheritence hierarchy, so be prepared to check whether this breaks with every Django version change.

Comment: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'required'

Comment: Then the better solution is probably indeed to have your `field` class subclass `forms.fields.CharField` instead of the bare base `Field` class!

Comment: I tried to turn field into django.forms.fields, doesn't work either.